# How do I use a latexmkrc file to allow a standalone document to find the file

Tags: standalone, latexmk, overleaf

I am using LaTex in Overleaf to write my Thesis Proposal and eventually the Disseration.  I thought it would be good to have all of these documents (and their presentations) in one project so I wouldn't have to keep duplicating projects and can easily share files.

The proposal PAPER is currently the "default document" in the Overleaf project.  I have a pretty extensive file structure to keep things organized, including "common" package and preamble files for papers and beamer presentations.

The proposal PRESENTATION is a stand alone document.  Bottom line, Overleaf can't seem to find the preamble/package documents for the stand alone document.

A little searching led to the use of a latexmkrc to convince the default document to search there first for my custom preambles and such.

However, I cannot figure out how to get my standalone beamer presentation to look at the latexmkrc file before trying to compile as a standalone.

Here's my attempt at showing the code:

In the default document (in the main Overleaf file structure) the following works and finds my style files:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{import}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

% Preamble
\usepackage{preamble}
```

In the standalone file (which is in its own folder) the following does not work:

```
\documentclass[xcolor = {usenames,dvipsnames,table},beamer]{standalone}

\usepackage{import}

% Preamble
\usepackage{beamer_preamble}
```

preamble and beamer_preamble are both .sty files which reside in a folder called "custom" which is in a folder called "support".  My latexmkrc file has the following code:

```
$ENV{'TEXINPUTS'}='./support/custom//:' . $ENV{'TEXINPUTS'};
```

Does anyone know how to get an Overleaf standalone file to check the latexmkrc file before compiling?

Comment: I sent an e-mail to Overleaf support.  I did try putting a latexmkrc file in the subfolder, but that didn't work.  I was reviewing your example project but then hit a back button and now when I click on your link it "cannot be found".

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) Watch me eat my words Jennifer! Mea culpa. I previously left a comment because I thought I had worked this out, but I didn't notice a flaw in my testing. So, it doesn't work like I thought it did. :-( Whether this can be done probably depends on your specific project structure. If you write to us at support@overleaf.com with your project's URL, we can take a look to see if there's any way to make this work.

Comment: That would explain why the link didn't work anymore!  Any help is appreciated.  I like things "clean and sleek" and want to do as little duplicate work as possible.  I feel like the ability to keep "related" documents in one Overleaf project is a pretty important capability.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I need to just put an answer to close this out.

The Overleaf folks suggested a slightly different file structure that mostly works.  Basically, all my "main" documents should be in the highest structure.